# HEMT device not entering breakdown region on Silvaco TCAD during IdVd analysis.What must I do to cause my device to breakdown?

Tags: mosfet, saturation, breakdown

I've been trying to create a HEMT device over the past couple of weeks in Silvaco TCAD. My device works just fine in low voltage operation- that is, IdVg and IdVd curves are as expected. I'm getting a clear cutoff, linear and saturation region.

The problem however, is with high voltage analysis- specifically breakdown analysis. My AlGaN-GaN HEMT won't break down regardless of how high a potential difference I apply across it. I've done the obvious, which is checking what physical models and mathematical models I'm using. I'm using Selberherr’s Model for impact ionisation, along with field mobility, srh, fermi and pch.elec models. All of these should suffice for breakdown analysis of a device- atleast they do in ganfetex02, Silvaco's inbuilt example.

At first, I was using a complicated field plated structure with several other shenanigans attached, so I thought the covoluted structure was the problem. However, upon re-trying on a barebones AlGaN-GaN only HEMT structure, I still obtained the same lack of breakdown.

I have included this code along with seemingly infinite saturation characteristics of my device. Any help on what models I should change or any parameters to modify is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

IdVd curve obtained:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKYUU.png

code of barebones HEMT structure:

````
#basic HEMT structure and analysing breakdown

go atlas


#meshing defintion
mesh width=50

x.mesh l=0 s=0.05
x.mesh l=1 s=0.05

y.mesh l=-0.05 s=0.05
y.mesh l=0.09 s=0.05
y.mesh l=0.1 s=0.01
y.mesh l=0.15 s=0.01
y.mesh l=0.20 s=0.05
y.mesh l=0.30 s=0.05


#region defintion

region num=1 mat=air y.min=-0.05 y.max=0.3
region num=2 mat=AlGan y.min=0 y.max=0.1 donors=3e17
region num=3 mat=GaN y.min=0.1 y.max=0.3 donors=1e15

#electrode definition

elec num=1 name=source y.min=-0.05 y.max=0.15 x.min=0 x.max=0.05
elec num=2 name=drain y.min=-0.05 y.max=0.15 x.min=0.95 x.max=1
elec num=3 name=gate y.min=-0.05 y.max=0 x.min=0.45 x.max=0.55

#doping definition

doping gaussian characterisitic=0.01 conc=1e19 n.type x.left=0 x.right=0.09 \
y.top=0.1 y.bottom=0.19 ratio.lateral=0.01 direction=y

doping gaussian characterisitic=0.01 conc=1e19 n.type x.left=0.91 x.right=1 \
y.top=0.1 y.bottom=0.19 ratio.lateral=0.01 direction=y

doping gaussian characterisitic=0.01 conc=3e17 n.type x.left=0 x.right=1 \
y.top=0 y.bottom=0.1 ratio.lateral=0.01 direction=y

doping gaussian characterisitic=0.01 conc=1e15 n.type x.left=0 x.right=1 \
y.top=0.1 y.bottom=0.3 ratio.lateral=0.01 direction=y


#displaying the structure
save outf=basicStructure.str
tonyplot basicStructure.str

#models definition

model print fermi fldmob srh pch.elec
impact selb

#contact definition

contact name=gate workfunction=4.8

#method specification

method newton itlim=35 trap  maxtrap=10 carriers=1  

output con.band val.band band.param charge e.mob h.mob flowlines qss

#idvd analysis

solve init

log outf=basicHEMT.log

solve  vstep=0.1 vfinal=1  name=drain
solve  vstep=1   vfinal=10 name=drain
solve  vstep=2   vfinal=20 name=drain
solve  vstep=5  vfinal=1200 name=drain cname=drain compl=1.0

save outf=basicStructure.str
tonyplot basicHEMT.log

quit
```
````